# How can I show a image on the main Github Wiki page

Tags: github, wiki

I am trying to find out why I can't show an image on my home.md page.
Images on other pages are working.

Home.md

```
![GOO Components Mindmap](images/GOOComponents.png) Not working
```

Genstart-Solr.md

```
![Fanen SolrLoadBalancer](images/SolrLoadBalancer.png) Working
```

All *.md files are in the root, images in the images folder.
I have tried to put the working images on the home page, but without any success.

Comment: Could it be that `GOOComponents.png` does not exist, the way it is spelled? It is case sensitive.

Comment: I can not show any images on the home page.

Comment: Could you clarify what we are talking about the wiki pages or about *.md files are just placed in your repo?

Comment: Oh, I understand this issue: it's because of different base for relative links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the fact that Github is different resolves relative links from home wiki page and other pages. More precisely the difference in the address of the main page and the rest.

You can see it if you open your wiki pages. I'll have:

https://github.com/User/Repo/**wiki** - for `home` page, and

https://github.com/User/Repo/**wiki/somePage** for others

SO you just need to use such src url in your home page:

`![GOO Components Mindmap](wiki/images/GOOComponents.png)`

Comment: Of course you can also use the absolute links to the images: `![GOO Components Mindmap](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/User/Repo/images/GOOComponents.png)`